# Renaming all the .csv in a folder

Tags: python, csv, operating-system

I want to rename all the .csv files to suppose say mac&cheese_12012010, mac&cheese_13012010, mac&cheese_14012010, mac&cheese_15012010, mac&cheese_16012010.......to only the part after '_'.
I wanna remove mac&cheese basically and retain the dates in python.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What problems did you run into? Please share your code and people will be able to help with issues you may be having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

# Change the directory
folder = r'E:\demos\files\reports\\'
# For Windows folder = r'E:/demos/files/reports/'

for file_name in os.listdir(folder):
    if file_name.endswith(".csv"):
        source = folder + file_name
    
        # We only want the dates
        destination = file_name.split('_')[1] +".csv"

        # Renaming the file
        os.rename(source, destination)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.rename`.

```py
import glob, os

for old in glob.glob('mac&cheese_*.csv'):
    new = old[len('mac&cheese_'):]
    os.rename(old, new)
```

Note that on linux, it seems that it overwrites destination files if they exist. On Windows, it does not seem to overwrite files. Anyway, **be cautious** when dealing with files.

Also, with python 3.9+, you can replace

`new = old[len('mac&cheese_'):]`

with

`new = old.removeprefix('mac&cheese_')`

which is better for readability. Just *don't* use `old.lstrip()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this code in the directory where the files are

```py
import os

# ONELINER
[os.rename(f, f.replace("mac&cheese_", "")) for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(".csv")]
```

#### OR

```py
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        os.rename(file, file.replace("mac&cheese_", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods including:

```
import glob
import os
files = glob.glob('/path/to/files/*.csv')
for file in files:
    new_name = file.replace('mac&cheese_','')
    os.rename(file,new_name)
```